# Dimming Lights without PWM. Possible?

Tags: home-automation

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to dim a light, using python to get 0%....50%...100% and various % brightnesses in between. Taking a PWM approach in the code means a flickering light, which won't work for the lower % brightness, as the flicker will become more apparent (eg at 3% brightness). I can't seem to find a method to code brightness level without PWM, but there must be! Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: If you see flicker increase the frequency.

Comment: In addition to @joan's solution (the easiest), there **may** also be the possibility of a constant current source, or a triac for AC. But as you've not explained exactly what it is you want to do, there's nothing else we can do to help.

Comment: What sort of light is it? And how is it powered?